# How to select the interface in Jetty client

Tags: java, jetty

I want to send a http request via a virtual interface. I'm able to do it with Apache Http-Client :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = client.getParams();
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.10.20"));
```

How can I do this in Jetty's Http-Client?

Comment: Since I couldn't find the way to do it in Jetty client, I migrated my application to Apache Http Client...
Still, if anyone finds the solution, answer it as it would be useful for someone else...

Answer (score 0):

Docs for the Jetty client are here with plenty of examples:

http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/http-client-api.html